# log into website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a website where the user logs in. When creating accounts, I check to see if the username already exists. Should this checking be done inside the scripts or should I make the username a primary key of the table? I'm using MySQL and PHP.

So should I write a script that queries the database to check to see if the supplied username is already in use or should I try inserting the given user name and  have the field as a primary key and if it fails it means that the user name is in use?

Comment: I wouldn't make the username the primary key, but I would suggest a unique constraint...

Comment: You can add a unique constraint to the username column without making it the primary key.

Comment: that depends on if user accounts can ever get deactivated and then reactivated for "new" users later.

Comment: At the very least it should be a unique constraint.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson What's the drawback of making the username the primary key?

Comment: What difference would it make having the username as a primary key vs constraint? Could you please elaborate so I know the pros/cons.

Comment: if username is primary key, you can only ever have **ONE** record with that username. let's say your site takes off and lasts for 200 years. "fred" who signed up in 2000 will be dead by 2100, but now fred can never EVER be used as a username again later on. so fred #2 in 2101 is out of luck.

Comment: There can be only one "fred" either way (if that's the login username). Primary key or not

Comment: The **primary** key cannot change, whereas a username can. It is primary in that it should not be changed, a username should have the ability to be changed so making it "primary" is not a good idea. So you should use a separate field for this reason with a unique index.

Comment: Are we talking about the login name or the display name?

Comment: @PeeHaa, you asked, "What difference would it make having the username as a primary key vs constraint?". I answered "relations". Because, it is better practice to have "smaller" data for relation ids. Example: user.id, user.username (id is int primary, username could be unique), then we have user_log.user_id, comment.user_id and-so-on. user.username can be changed, and relations stay the same, so no need for multiple table update's.

Comment: Again are we talking about login names or display names?

Comment: @PeeHaa login name is what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the approach of putting a unique constraint on the username field in the database, and then just trying an insert  on the database. Don't check for the existing username first, as this is just an unnecessary query.

You can then evaluate the mysql response to determine if the insert failed due to duplicate key or whether something else went wrong.